# Combine answer from row in one cell according to max date

Tags: google-sheets

Could someone help me to solve the task?

I have a Google Form, that collect information about meetings (date, tasks, deadline).
I need to combine date from every row in one cell with the following logic.
Date of the meeting (maximum date from 10 cells)
Task 1 of this meeting (deadline) -
Task 2 of this meeting (deadline)

Date of the meeting (second maximum date from 10 cells)
Task 1 of this meeting (deadline) -
Task 2 of this meeting (deadline)

Date of the meeting (last (10) maximum date from 10 cells)
Task 1 of this meeting (deadline) -
Task 2 of this meeting (deadline)

Number of meetings in each row can be from 0 to 10
Number of tasks from 1 to 5

It would be great to solve task with arrayrange formula.

Also link with an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eGo5M1P1OmPU09jND7clc2fn7Z3Awe2JEpf2IhNvuE0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(if(CD2:CD="";; vlookup(row(CD2:CD)&""; trim(split(transpose(query(query(split(transpose(split(textjoin(""; true; if(CD2:CD="";; if((mod(column(CD2:GS)-9; 12) = 1) * (CD2:GS <> ""); "\" & row(CD2:GS) & "~|" & CD2:GS & "|" & char(10) & "Meeting from " & text(CD2:GS; "dd.mm.yyyy"); if(isodd(column(CD2:GS)-9) * (CD2:GS<>""); char(10) & (mod(column(CD2:GS)-9;12) - 1)/2 & ". " & CD2:GS & " (" & text(CE2:GT; "dd.mm.yyyy") & ")"; ))));"\")); "|"); "select Col2, max(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1 order by Col2 desc label Col2 'date' ");; 999)); "~"));2;false)))
```